# Bootstrap collapse OnePage - hide after click on 'a'

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, fullpage.js

I want create a OnePage site and I created sidebar on bootstrap collapse.
Now I want to hide this sidebar and go to section, after click on the link but it's not working.
Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" id="sidebar-wrapper" role="navigation">
        <ul class="nav sidebar-nav">
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="closed" data-toggle="offcanvas">zamknij</a>
            </li>
            <li class="sidebar-brand">
                <a href="#">
                    Brand
                </a>
            </li>
            <li data-menuanchor="firstPage">
                <a href="#firstPage">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li data-menuanchor="secondPage">
                <a href="#secondPage">About</a>
            </li>
            <li data-menuanchor="3rdPage">
                <a href="#3rdPage">Events</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

            <button type="button" class="sidebar is-closed" data-toggle="offcanvas">
                X
            </button>
```

and **JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var trigger = $('.sidebar');
    var CloseIcon = $('.closed');
    var NavElement = $('.nav li a');

    trigger.click(function () { 
        trigger.collapse( 'hide' );
    });

    CloseIcon.click(function () {    
        trigger.show( 'slow' );
    });

    NavElement.click(function() {
        trigger.collapse( 'hide' );
    });


    $('[data-toggle="offcanvas"]').click(function () {
        $('#wrapper').toggleClass('toggled');
    }); 

    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
        navigation: true,
        menu: '.sidebar-nav',
        autoScrolling: false,
        navigationPosition: 'right',
        navigationTooltips: ['First page', 'Second page', 'Third and last page'],
    });

});
```

I using FullPage.js

**EDIT** Here is JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dxg7Lep2/

Comment: I can't find `sidebar` class in your HTML code.

Comment: Ouhh, sorry, I forgot about this :P This is button to open sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what's wrong with your test, if you create a jsfiddle I can have a look at it. I did create one to try to replicate the behaviour but works fine for me.

http://jsfiddle.net/Dhanck/ytryL4zy/2/

```
$('#fullpage').fullpage({
     sectionsColor: ['#1bbc9b', '#4BBFC3', '#7BAABE', 'whitesmoke', '#ccddff'],
     anchors: ['firstPage', 'secondPage', '3rdPage', '4thpage', 'lastPage'],
     menu: '.sidebar-nav',
     css3: true,
     scrollingSpeed: 1000
   });
```